# PHP string concatenation

Tags: php, string-concatenation

Is it possible to concatenate strings, as follows? And if not, what is the alternative of doing so?

```
while ($personCount < 10) {
    $result += $personCount . "person ";
}

echo $result;
```

It should appear like `1 person 2 person 3` person, etc.

You can’t use the `+` sign in concatenation, so what is the alternative?

Comment: You are actually using the "alternative" in your example code.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that no-one has pointed out that you are using "people" instead of "person".

Comment: The bigger question is WHY  does php use "." instead of "+" for string concatenation? I mean.. Seriously?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just use `.` for concatenating.
And you missed out the `$personCount` increment!

```
while ($personCount < 10) {
    $result .= $personCount . ' people';
    $personCount++;
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 10):

One step (IMHO) better

```
$result .= $personCount . ' people';
```

Answer (score 7):

This should be faster.

```
while ($personCount < 10) {
    $result .= "{$personCount} people ";
    $personCount++;
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Care to cite any evidence that `"{$personCount} people"` is faster than `$personCount . ' people'`?  Otherwise it just seems like wild speculation...

Comment: PHP is forced to re-concatenate with every '.' operator. It is better to use double quotes to concatenate.

Comment: @Abdul Alim Shakir: But there is only one concatenation, so it shouldn't make any difference(?).

Comment: Using `.` instead `.=` (the first instance) *does* affect performance (probably due to the [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm) - this can happen in *any* language or system), but it is ***already*** using `.=`.

Comment: cont': From *[Assignment Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)*: *"Using `$text .= "additional text";` instead of `$text = $text . "additional text";` can seriously enhance performance due to memory allocation efficiency. I reduced execution time from 5 seconds to 0.5 seconds (10 times) by simply switching to the first pattern for a loop with 900 iterations over a string $text that reaches 800K by the end."*

Answer (score 6):

```
while ($personCount < 10) {
    $result .= ($personCount++)." people ";
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work fine:

```php
while ($personCount < 10) {
    $result = $personCount . "people ';
    $personCount++;
}
# I do not understand why you need the (+) with the result.
echo $result;
```

Comment: See that you have `"people '` instead of `'people '`.

Comment: You will probably get a load of errors because of what @PhoneixS has pointed out: mismatched quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$personCount = 1;
while ($personCount < 10) {
    $result = 0;
    $result .= $personCount . "person ";
    $personCount++;
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.