# How do I concatenate a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to echo a PHP function with some string literal HTML.

This is how I thought it was done:

```
echo '<a href="' + $prevpost->url()  + '" class="postnav left nextpost"></a>';
```

...but that returns nothing. I've tried small variations on where the quotes are etc. but I'm worried I'm barking up the wrong tree and I can't really find what I need from searching.

Note: `echo $prevpost->url();` does return the URL I am trying to link to, before anybody asks if that works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP string concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation)

Comment: Hi, questions like this can be easily solved by Googling the question title. Always remember to do that first. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to below, in php `.` (dot) is used as a concatenation operation in php,

```
echo '<a href="' . $prevpost->url()  . '" class="postnav left nextpost"></a>';
```

Answer (score 7):

The concatenation operator in PHP is `.` and not `+`

Answer (score 3):

the concatenator in PHP is the `.` operator

Answer (score 3):

Like other people have mentioned, the PHP concatenation operator is `.` rather than `+`.

However, instead of string concatenation, you can use commas when using PHP's `echo()` function to gain a [*small* speed improvement over concatenation](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/).

Your code would then look like:

```
echo '<a href="',  $prevpost->url(), '" class="postnav left nextpost"></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot to concatenate or

```
echo "<a href='{prevpost->url()}' class='postnav left nextpost'></a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In almost any other language we use the **+** operator, but in php we use the **.** operator for the concatinating. Try to replace the **+** with **.**:

```
echo '<a href="' . $prevpost->url()  . '" class="postnav left nextpost"></a>';
```