# Add spaces between results

Tags: php

I have the following code and output

```
for ($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
if ($i % 2!=0)
echo $i + "";


?>
```

13579111315171921232527293133353739414345474951535557596163656769717375777981838587899193959799
The problem is that there is no space between the numbers. How do I add this space

Comment: That is one question!

Comment: Hmmm it's a bit odd :P

Comment: even shorter: `for($i=1; $i<=100; $i+=2){ echo "$i "; }`

Comment: My guess at this point is that if they didn't know how to add a space, it's important to have readability before having as little as possible. @CORRUPT Nice though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP string concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `echo $i + "";` to `echo $i . " ";`

Comment: And start thinking, it really helps while programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
  if ($i % 2!=0)
      echo "$i ";
```