# How To Get Multiple HTML Page URL into PHP

Tags: php, html

I am working on one assignment. I had to write code for sending the report in email.
When I open HTML page and click on the button then it sends in email.

BUT suppose I have 10 reports, and I want that when I click on send button it should send in email.
Because I have used

`$html=file_get_contents("html_report.html");`

in PHP code. It works for only html_report.html but I want it to work for rest 10 files.

For example : I have 1.html,2.html...10.html,I want to that whenever I open any HTML file and click on the button then it should send. So what should I write in

`$html=file_get_contents(`*"WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE"*`);`

so that it will work for 10 files.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `file_get_contents` inside loop

Comment: Try researching first before asking a question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11441389/2301271

Comment: @Roopendra I don't want a loop. I want URL of each page in **file_get_contents**.

Comment: Do you want to put content from all files in one email, or choose and send one of reports?

Comment: do You want to send 10 reports in a single email?

Comment: @MarkS No. I just want that whenever I send it should work for all 10 files.

Comment: @AwladLiton No. I just want that whenever I send it should work for all 10 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

Say, you want to send report by mail. your first report is in `report1.html` file. you want to send this report. say, you are using a php file named `sendReport.php`  to sending email.

now, send a parameter in your file like this  :

```
yourhost.com/sendReport.php?file=report1.html
```

in your `sendReport.php` get file name like this:

```
$fileName = $_GET['file'];
```

then get report html like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents($fileName);
```

then send your mail with report which is in `$html`

for every report file just pass right report file name in your url like this: `yourhost.com/sendReport.php?file=your_file_name.html`
I think it makes sense!

**EDIT:**

You should send a parameter for file name in your url like this:

```
yoursite.com?file=your_html_file_name
```

then in your mail sending page get file name:

```
$fileName = $_GET['file'];
```

then get report html like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents($fileName);
```

then send your mail

Comment: Hi Awlad, Yes I want to do this.Can you explain me a bit further?

Comment: @Kalpesh Singh: i have updated my answer.

Comment: So I have to added **email.php?file=C:\xampp\htdocs\test\email report\report_ledger.html** in Button and added rest two function in email.php but getting error. **Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\email report\email.php on line 6**

Comment: just pass the name email.php?file=report_ledger.html

Comment: No,It is not working. Getting same error.

Comment: Hi Awlad, Your solution is 100% right. I have add this in the link instead of the button and it works! Thanks man..You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

add this code on the page who's url you want to use:

```
<?php $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

and then use this url from session

Comment: Can you explain it further?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the array to loop all those html file.LIKE:

```
$reports = array("1.html", "2.html", "3.html", ...... "10.html");
```

then loop the $reports.

```
foreach ($reports as $report) {
   $html = file_get_contents("WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE");
   ........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

to get the current url.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get HTML in loop and then send email.

```
<?php
$arrTemplates = array('html_report1.html','html_report2.html','html_report3.html','html_report4.html','html_report10.html');
foreach($arrTemplates as $htmlFileName) {
    $html=file_get_contents($htmlFileName);
    // CODE FOR SEND EMAIL
}
?>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**With For Loop**

```
<?php
for ($x=1; $x<=10; $x++)
{
$html=file_get_contents("html_report".$x.".html");
// Send email
}
?>
```

**With arrays**

```
<?php
$reports=array("page1.html","page2.html","page3.html");
$arrlength=count($reports);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
{
$html=file_get_contents($reports[$x]);
// send Email
}
?>
```