# How I can print value in header function

Tags: php, header

I had a small problem when I try to write this code.

```
header("Location: question.php?id='$qid'");
```

It prints this:

> question.php?id='$qid

But this not what I want, I want to print the value of `$qid`,

Comment: try this header("Location: question.php?id={$qid}");

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP string concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: question.php?id=$qid");
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Recommended version:

```
header("Location: question.php?$qid");
```

This way trick also work for me if you separate as variable:

```
$redirect = 'question.php?'.$qid;
header('Location: '.$redirect);
```

It is also good to set type of redirecting HTTP status as:

```
header("Location: question.php?$qid", TRUE, 301);
```

Which means that it will moved permanently as status code 301 and replace a data to changed values. Please see PHP.net manual for [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Don't forget to add exit(); status if you want to prevent for buffering output if you have some errors or unexpected stopped as sample:

```
header("Location: question.php?$qid", TRUE, 301);
exit();
```

Here is HTTP sample code on Wiki how it really works behind PHP header(): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx

Answer (score -2):

```
header("Location: question.php?id='".$qid."'");
```

Comment: @Blackberry try `header("Location: question.php?id=$qid");` or
`header("Location: question.php?id=".$qid);`

Comment: Granted this user's answer most likely won't work, but don't just say "didn't work" - report back with more details. What happened when you tried it? In this case, since it's in a URL, it probably threw excess quotes in, right? BTW, @meda has the right idea.

Comment: I add the single quotes because I don't know if you needed them, but you can simply remove them and end up with @meda suggestion...