# How to store all result from a loop and each result separated by a comma?

Tags: php, arrays, glob

Currently I have this working PHP code for search photos inside a folder by name:

```
$dirname = "photos";
$filenames = glob("$dirname/*{380,381,382,383,384,385}*", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    echo $filename . "<br>";
}
```

I have typed manualy those numbers `380,381,382,383,384,385` and I would like to have them typed exactly the same but automatically.

If I'm not wrong we have to do an **array()** on this code:

```
$start = 380;
$end = 385;

for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
    echo "$i<br>";
}
```

I haven't found how to store the whole loop inside a variable for reproduce the same result as the first code but automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP string concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to create the array with the numbers, which you then can [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) into a string, e.g.

```
$filenames = glob("$dirname/*{" . implode(",", range(308, 385)) . "}*", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = range(380, 385);
$string = '{' . implode(',', $array) . '}';
```