# php how to loop append to variable

Tags: php

I have this PHP code that works:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    do stuff to $class
    echo "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star $class\"></i>";
}
```

Instead of using `echo` in the loop, how would I append each iteration to a variable (say `$stars`) and then be able to display the result with

```
echo "$stars";
```

Comment: `echo` => `$stars.=`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation)

Comment: Also FYI, `echo $stars;` has the same effect as `echo "$stars";`. The double quotes aren't necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a variable to hold your HTML. Concatenate the HTML to this variable instead of echoing it.

After the loop you can echo that variable.

```
$stars = '';
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    // do stuff to $class
    $stars .= "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star $class\"></i>";
}
echo $stars;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Concatenation assignment `.=` like this

```
$var='';
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    do stuff to $class
    $var.="<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star $class\"></i>";
}
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do this without modifying your existing code using output buffering.

```
// start a new output buffer
ob_start();

for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    //do stuff to $class

    // results of these echo statements go to the buffer instead of immediately displaying
    echo "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star $class\"></i>";
}

// get the buffer contents
$stars = ob_get_clean();
```

For a simple thing like this I would still use concatenation with `.=` as shown in the other answers, but just FYI.