# how to Insert comma between values in php

Tags: php

My value is coming like this with two enters. please see below :

```
125

124

132
```

I am getting this value by php variable and want to get values with commas in new php variable.

i want like this 125,124,132

anyone have an idea for that please?

Comment: Show your php code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation)

Comment: Please show your PHP code so we know what you have now.

Comment: Please show us the code that gets those values. It's much easier for us to give you a proper answer if we know the context.

Comment: @AmanKumar You mean `implode()`?

Comment: @kerbholz - If the OP gets that in a string, you would need to explode it first, remove all empty rows and then do an implode. But since the OP doesn't seem to want to show us the code, it's anyone's guess :-/

Comment: @MagnusEriksson True, overread the "two enters" in OPs question, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "125

124

132";

$str = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", ",", $str);
echo $str;
```

Try the above code. Please let know if this worked.

Comment: It is working fine. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it worked.!!

Answer (score -1):

You can directly add commas between numbers using

`number_format()` ***function of PHP***

```
<?php
  echo number_format("125124132")."<br>";
?>
```

Answer:- 1**25,124,132**

Try the above given code and let me know if this worked.....