# concatenate two strings and pass it to array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The Line 2 fetches the value fall 2017 and line 3 fetches fall 2018 and stores into the array semesters_info.

How to fetch Line 2 and line 3 data (fall 2017,fall 2018) and store into the array?

```
$semesters_info = (array) null;
 $semesters_info += [$semesters->fall_term_cd => $semesters->fall_term_name];
$semesters_info += [$semesters->spring_term_cd => $semesters->spring_term_name];
```

I have tried but errors out to array to string conversion error.-

```
 $test1= [$semesters->spring_term_cd => $semesters->spring_term_name];
$test2 = [$semesters->fall_term_cd => $semesters->fall_term_name];
$semesters_info += $test1.''.$test2;
```

Currently Semester info will store Fall 2017 and Spring 2018, I would need a third value which is Fall 2017 Spring 2018.

Comment: You need the correct concatenation operator, `.=`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation

Comment: Why are you doing `$semesters_info = (array) null;`? What is wrong with `$semesters_info = array();` or the new-ish `$semesters_info = [];`

Comment: You may need to use the php doc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: $semesters_info += [$semesters->fall_term_cd => $semesters->fall_term_name.=$semesters->spring_term_cd => $semesters->spring_term_name]; I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']' error

Comment: Edit your post and describe what is in input and how should look output.

Comment: It's either `$semesters_info = array(); $semesters_info[$semesters->fall_term_cd] = $semesters->fall_term_name; $semesters_info[$semesters->spring_term_cd] = $semesters->spring_term_name;` or `$semesters_info = $semesters->fall_term_name." ".$semesters->spring_term_name;` depending if you want string or array with the values

Comment: If you use the latter one (concatenate string) you can add it into array like this: `$semester_info[] = $string;`