# How can I append user input to an email address (domain part) when sending it to MySql with PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Note: email address structure is `local-part@domain`.

For example I am asking user to provide his email:

```html
<label>Your Gmail:</label><input type="email" name="emailaddress"><label>@gmail.com</label>
```

But instead of letting him/her type the complete email address (e.g. user@gmail.com), I want to let user type only local-part without domain. But how can I send this email to MySql database now? Basically I need to append custom input to `@gmail.com` every time user submits the form. For example, records in my database would look like `user1@gmail.com`, `user2@gmail.com` etc.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It is not clear what you need. If you submit the form where this field is in, it will arrive at the server. Perhaps you need Ajax?

Comment: You'll have to put your MySQL insertion routine in your question so we can add in the appending of the string for you. Something like: `$email .= '@gmail.com';`.

Comment: Please add sql code for insert opertaion.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I was thinking about doing it this way - basically concatenating strings. e.g. I have `$email = $_POST['email'];` and then I would `$email .= '@gmail.com';` I will try it and let you know. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried in my local works perfect.

```
$email = $_POST['email'] //Text box value
$email = $email."@gmail.com";
```

You are required to do some concatenation like above

Answer (score 1):

In PHP build a String like this.

```
$email = $_REQUEST['emailaddress'];
echo "$email@gmail.com";
```

if the value submitted by the form was `john.smith`, the output would be

> john.smith@gmail.com

---

Read [PHP 5 Form Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) to understand how to retrieve the parameters parsed by the form.