# How to add a file extension to the file its grabbing

Tags: php

How do I add a file extension to this code so its looking for a .zip

So this script works perfectly if i do url.com?sn=123 - it will delete a file called 123, however how do add the .zip in the code so it actually says if file 123.zip exists then unlink 123.zip

```
<?PHP
 if (file_exists($_GET["sn"])) {
        unlink($_GET["sn"]);
    } else {
        // File not found.
    }

?>
```

I tried doing this: (however it just errors)

```
<?PHP
$zip=".zip";
 if (file_exists($_GET['sn'],['zip'])) {
        unlink($_GET['sn'],['zip']);
    } else {
        // File not found.
    }

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<?PHP
$file_name = $_GET['sn'].'.zip';
if (file_exists($file_name)) {
    unlink($file_name);
} else {
    // File not found.
}
?>
```

Comment: Great, I'm glad that worked!  Do you mind clicking the accept check mark to the left of my answer?  You can learn more about accepting answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers